# UITabBar in Landscape with UITableView in Portrait

Tags: iphone, uitableview, orientation

I am creating a large line graph, composed of several custom UIViews showing different sections of data within UITableViewCells, to facilitate easy scrolling of the graph.  The problem is, that since UITableViews don't support horizontal scrolling or more than one cell in any given row, I can only correctly view the data if, while the view is in portrait mode, I hold the iphone sideways.  However, this is a tab-based application, so the tabbar looks out of place when I do this.  I have been able to change the orientation of the top status bar, but how can I change the position of the tabbar to landscape, while keeping the uitableview portrait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to take a step back and build a custom view based on the UIScrollView rather than trying to use the UITableView to display your graph data.

Comment: Would it make sense to create a custom uiscrollview and draw directly onto it given size limitations of UIViews?  One benefit of the UITableView is its memory efficiency, in that it only draws what is visible on the screen at a given time.

Comment: You can add that efficiency to your own custom implementation.  A UITableView is just a UIScrollView with added functionality.